# Is it possible to upload a file from silverlight client to server using WCF streaming?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF file upload service, which is using streamed mode. Is it possible to consume this in a silverlight application?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a big fan of this one. It has worked great for us on some projects for Async Uploads via WCF: http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/08/using-transfermode-streamedresponse-to-download-files-in-silverlight-4.aspx) no but the post offers alternative (in SL 4).